# componentDidUpdate doesn't catch redux props update in different file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have 2 files, Channels.js and Messages.js

**Channels.js:**

```
class Channels extends React.Component {

...

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.currentChannel !== this.props.currentChannel) {
      if (this.props.currentChannel && this.props.currentChannel._id) {
        console.log("this.props.currentChannel updated")
      }
    }
  }

...

setFirstChannel = () => {
    const firstChannel = this.state.channels[0][0];

    if (this.state.firstLoad && this.state.channels[0].length > 0) {
      this.props.setCurrentChannel(firstChannel);
...

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    currentServer: state.server.currentServer,
    currentChannel: state.channel.currentChannel
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setCurrentChannel: async (channel) => await dispatch(setCurrentChannel(channel)),
    setPrivateChannel: async (isPrivateChannel) => await dispatch(setPrivateChannel(isPrivateChannel))
  }
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
  )(Channels));
```

Above componentDidUpdate actually works. It catches the change of **this.props.currentChannel** which is changed in setFirstChannel function by **this.props.setCurrentChannel(firstChannel);**

But the problem is to catch this in different file in **Messages.js**:

```
class Messages extends React.Component {

...

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.currentChannel !== this.props.currentChannel) {
      if (this.props.currentChannel && this.props.currentChannel._id) {
        console.log("This cannot catch the change that is done in Channels.js")
      }
    }
...

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    currentChannel: state.channel.currentChannel,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setUserPosts: async (userPosts) => await dispatch(setUserPosts(userPosts))
  }
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
  )(Messages));
```

Console.log in componentDidUpdate function of Messages.js doesn't print anything.
How do I solve this so that componentDidUpdate in both Channels.js and Messages.js catch the change of redux props?

Comment: @buzatto I don't think that is related to this problem. I just showed setUserPosts to just show if classes are connected to redux store using mapDispatchToProps. How is that related to the problem?

Comment: i know it has been some days. But have you check that you component is connected? maybe try to print the state before returning it in the mapstatetoprops before so you can make sure that you are receiving the state properly